# Нужен алгоритм для сравнения по уровням данным в массиве

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть объект с родственниками, они соотносятся друг к другу по типу: Родитель, Ребенок, Брат/Сестра, Равный

```
{
"parent": "Bill",
"parent": "Anna",
"children": [
    {
    "parent": "Mark",
    "parent": "Sara",
    "children": [
            { "parent": "Sofia" },
            { "parent": "Patric" },
            { "parent": "Marta" }
    ]}
]}
```

В БД есть таблици:

```
Peoples (id, name);
References (ENUM(parent, children, sibling), тут видимо надо будет дополнить);
```

Как задать между ними родственные связи, что бы это выглядело так:
Если я делаю запрос в БД для Anna, получаю:

```
"sibling": Bill,
"children": Mark,
"children": Sara,
```

Если я делаю запрос в БД для Marta, получаю:

```
"parent": Mark,
"parent": Sara,
"sibling": Sofia,
"sibling": Patric,
"sibling": Marta,
```

Вопрос не в том, как делать запрос, а как сравнивать их соотношение между собой и назначать роли относительно друг друга.

Например, получаем Bill и Anna смотрим, что они на одном уровне значит Bill для Anna -> sibling и наоборот и записываем эти связи в БД.

Например, получаем Mark и Anna смотрим, что Mark на уровень ниже Anna значит Anna для Mark имеет уровень -> parent а Mark для Anna имеет уровень -> children и записывем эти связи в БД.

П.С. Не будем придираться к неточностям родственных связей.

Comment: Не совсем ясна существующая структура... У Билла и Анны есть дети Марк и Сара, у которых другие дети? Простите, инцест? _Не будем придираться к неточностям родственных связей_ - но как тогда можно понять структуру?

Comment: Возможно не совсем точный пример, мне нужно выстроить references между элементами объекта. Когда есть родительский элемент, дочерний элемент и равный себе по иерархии. Например как на работе, есть начальник и подчиненный, при этот подчиненный может быть начальником уже у своего подчиненного и равным с другим подчиненным своего начальника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, можно придумать что-то очень костыльное, чтобы виды родственных связей были реализованы таблицей, но это будет очень плохое решение.

Вам нужна всего одна таблица:

People (id, name, father_id, mother_id)

А логику получения родственников целиком нужно вынести в код.

Comment: Тогда уж People (id, name, parrent_id, children_id, sibling_id) но shildren и sibling может быть много.

Comment: @SergeiR, нет, детей и сиблингов нужно получать запросом. Информации о родителях вполне достаточно, чтобы вычислить всех остальных родственников.

Comment: Спасибо, общая идея была верной, скорректировали мой поток сознания ))